# django cms gunicorn fails importing .wsgi file

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I try to install djangocms on a webserver. The problem is that my gunicorn service is getting an error when deploying the cms.

```
File "/home/hg3n/django-cms/cms-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
  __import__(module)
  ImportError: No module named 'cms.wsgi'
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7109)
[INFO] Shutting down: Master
[INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The whole structure looks like the following:

```
~/django-cms
| --- cms-env/
| --- cms
   | --- site/
      | ---__init__.py
      | ---__pycache__
      | ---settings.py
      | ---static
      | ---templates
      | ---urls.py
      | ---wsgi.py
   | --- manage.py
   | --- media/
   | --- project.db
   | --- requirements.txt
   | --- static/
```

I start the gunicorn service using the following command

`uberspace-setup-service gunicorn gunicorn --error-logfile - --reload --chdir /home/hg3n/django-cms/cms --bind 127.0.0.1:65164 cms.wsgi:application`

What is the problem, I'm familiar with python but new to django web developement.

#### EDIT:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:65164/\$1 [P]

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https env=HTTPS
```

Comment: Path to wsgi.py seems to be 'site.wsgi' - try it in the gunicorn's command line

Comment: that actually removed the error, but I still can't see my site on the web

Comment: Are you running it on your local computer or on remote web server? With the given command line it will listen port 65164 only on localhost, not from remote computers.

Comment: Its running on an Uberspace server, Their official tutorial on settingup django explained this command. As well as a .htaccess belonging to it.
If I install django without the cms everything is wrking fine with this command

Comment: So you're having gunicorn being proxied behind of Apache, right? Try to enable logfile and look what's happening there. From the server itself try to make 'wget http://127.0.0.1:65164' to get the output

Comment: the log looks normal to me except this line: `return f(*args, **kwds)` als it says its booted up and listening on 127.0.0.1:64164. I also added the htacces to my inital question

Comment: What does `wget` return on local request? What do you see in your browser? Try to trace the external request by apache's log files - you can find out if it cannot reach your service.
The root cause might be any sort of - maybe you did not install some libraries or use wrong python version... Need logs and output.

Comment: If I use wget I get the correct index.html. If I try to reach the website I just get  a 503 saying that the server is unreachable. I think due to the fact that there are multiple users located on one server I cannot get a valuable log from apache

Comment: If so - your gunicorn-django stack works well. The problem might be in Apache. Do you have mod_rewrite enabled there? Have you configured virtualhost section correctly? Do you have access to apache's configuration at all?

Comment: I searched a bit but it seems like I don't have access to the configs. The weird thing is that Installing django without cms works with the exact same commands.

Comment: Cannot say more without looking into logs, sorry.

Comment: @hGen Did you add `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` to your settings.py file? You need this setting when you proxy gunicorn behind apache.